# Are there any 'protected' names you should avoid in Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails and I just wondered if there were any protected names you should avoid using in your models? For example, would the following be valid:

```
class CreateModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :model do |t|
      t.string :hash
      t.integer :count

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I realise has probably isn't a great name for a property, but it's a pure example.

Edit: All the responses were good, but I've chosen my accepted answer because it contains a link to a huge list of protected attributes.

Comment: You're right it is a duplicate! I didn't find that one searching though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally ran into an issue where I named my model `record`:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11645
- [ActiveRecord belongs_to association does not save foreign_key (Rails 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521593/activerecord-belongs-to-association-does-not-save-foreign-key-rails-4)

Other than that:

- http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/
- [Reserved names with ActiveRecord models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750009/reserved-names-with-activerecord-models)

Comment: Superb - thanks for the links!

Answer (score 3):

Avoid class names, if they are defined:

```
!!defined? Class  # => true
!!defined? Model  # => false
```

Avoid column names within this list:

- **id** - Reserved for primary keys
- **lock_version**
- **type** - single table inheritance and must contain a class name
- **table_name_count** - Reserved for counter cache
- **position** - Reserved for acts_as_list
- **parent_id** - Reserved for acts_as_tree
- **lft** - Reserved for acts_as_nested_set
- **rgt** - Reserved for acts_as_nested_set
- **quote** - Method in ActiveRecord::Base which is used to quote SQL
- **template**

Comment: I don't think those will be a problem. Thanks for the `defined` headsup!

Answer (score 1):

I can remember only two:

1. `type`, because Rails treats this property as a type of parent object in polymorphic objects.
2. `order` and any other SQL commands/statements/etc., because Rails generating SQL queries is using them and usually an exception occurs.

Comment: I see. They both make sense and should be easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issues with an external db and a column named "hash".
The offending column can be ignored in this manner:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self # Class methods
    alias :all_columns :columns 

    def columns 
      all_columns.reject {|c| c.name == 'hash'} 
    end 
  end 
end
```