# JSON object size in rails includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get all `transactions` in a `postgresql db`, `transactions` have a one-to-one relationship with the `pairs` table. In the pairs table, there's a column called `match` with type json. I want to select all `transactions` including their `pair` whose `pair.match` count is greater than 1.

I tried `pairs = Pair.where('json_array_length(match) > 1')` which worked.

How do I get all transactions where `pair.match` is greater than 1. Tried this -> `transactions = Transactions.includes(:pair).where(pairs: 'json_array_length(match) > 1')` but didn't work.

Update: It's `Transaction` not `Transactions`

Answer (score 2):

A couple of observations:

1. The model should be "Transaction" (singular)
2. You are really setting yourself up for a world of hurt by naming it "Transaction".  That's basically a "reserved word".  You don't want to use it.  You're going to have collisions with other places where there's already a method called "transaction" or "transactions"
3. Same with having a column called "match". That's a really common method name in Ruby.

I know I'm not answering the question, but this is too much for a comment and you need to fix these issues before going on.

Comment: I made a mistake when typing. It's `Transaction`

Comment: More "protected" words that you should avoid in rails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287497

Comment: @larrybuntus You don't want to use "Transaction" whether it's singular or plural.  You will run into weird problems - just change the name of that table/model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try joining the two tables. Supposing that your models are Pair and Transaction

```
transactions = Transaction.joins(:pair).where('json_array_length(match) > 1')
```

Comment: Would this be slow if I have 1 million transactions and 1 million pairs?

Comment: I can't imagine any shortcut on this. It's a simple join between two tables. I agree with the observations of Michael Chaney though. You should adopt all proposed changes to avoid any problems in the future.